# maximum of column with matching id

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following fields

```
NM001 rp1 210
NM003 rp1 220
NM005 rag 200
NM004 rag 100
```

I would like to have an output that for every change in column2, find maximum in column4 but also report corresponding column1. So far I found a solution that report column2 and 3 but not column1 because the number in column1 is different.  I like to use awk please.

The output should be

```
NM003 rp1 220
NM005 rag 200
```

Comment: You are closing up on the point where it will be easier to write something in perl or pyton.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this quite easily with awk.

You need to keep track of the maximum value for each value in the second column, and you also want to keep the whole line for each which has the max value:

```
awk '
    $3 > maxvals[$2] {lines[$2]=$0; maxvals[$2]=$3}
    END { for (tag in lines) print lines[tag] }
'
```

The output is not sorted, so pipe into `sort` if you need a particular sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `sort` and `uniq` tools:

```
sort -k3,3nr infile |
awk '{ print $1" " $3" " $2 }' | 
uniq -f2 | awk '{ print $1" " $3" " $2 }' > outfile
```