# retaining highest match from a column for a uniq ID

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a tab delimited file with many columns:

```
1   A   10  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    bat
1   B   20  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    bear
1   C   12  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    dear
1   D   36  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    quinoa
1   R   55  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    quinoa
2   E   48  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    cat
2   F   62  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    cat
2   G   49  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    dog
2   H   13  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    whale
3   I   28  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    snake
3   J   95  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    lion
3   K   64  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    elephant
3   L   38  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    dog
3   M   19  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    fox
3   N   97  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    eagle
3   O   84  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    parrot
3   P   64  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    insect
3   Q   13  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    shark
3   R   49  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    rat
```

I want to retain rows with unique ID having largest number in column 3:

```
1   R   55  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    quinoa
2   F   62  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    cat
3   N   97  1.94E-31       N/A   N/A    eagle
```

My real file is having headers and column 3 contain numeric with decimal.

Comment: @Kusalananda https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16710/maximum-of-column-with-matching-id is close enough to be a dupe.  The other one isn't (it only works for 2-column input, so only needs one array rather than two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 {print ; next};
              $3 > largest[$1] { largest[$1]=$3; line[$1] = $0 };
              END { for (id in largest) { print line[id] }}' input.txt 
1       R       55      1.94E-31        N/A     N/A     quinoa
2       F       62      1.94E-31        N/A     N/A     cat
3       N       97      1.94E-31        N/A     N/A     eagle
```

This awk script uses two arrays, one to keep track of the largest value of $3 for each id ($1), and the second to record the associated input line.

Once all the input has been read and processed, it prints out the lines in id order.

The `NR==1 {print; next};` line just prints out the first (header) line verbatim and then skips to the next input line.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but in my data which is very large there are many ids with same numbers in 3rd column, can we then sort them on the basis of their e value in 4th column which should be minimum and if found same then retain the first entry only.

Comment: you can sort the input file before piping it into `awk` - e.g. `sort -k4,4 input.txt | awk .....`.   will make sure the awk script sees the lowest values for $4 first.  if you want it to see the highest values first, use `sort -r k4,4 | awk ...`.     Because the arrays are only updated when it sees a **larger** $3 value, the first one seen by the awk script will be the one kept in the array.